# Connecting multiple tables using Entity Framework (code first)

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I've created 2 table for my database, and connect them using foreign key,
example:

```
internal class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual  Group Group { get; set; }
}
internal class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

It works just fine, but then I had to join a third table (which is connected via foreign key with Group table). So I've changed my group table a bit, and created another table called Course

```
internal class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }


    //foreign key
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}

internal class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't work as I expected, cause when I'm trying to create a migration I'm getting this error message "The property 'GroupId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type."

Comment: Probably  `[ForeignKey("CourseId")]` and set attribute above `Course` property.

Comment: Thx for your answer, could you explain what kind of attribute should i set, and where. Cause I created FK the same way as I did with GroupId, and it worked just fine. P.s. I changed ForeignKey name as u mansioned

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation indicates that, in your case, ForeignKey takes the field name of your "Group" dependent entity;
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

So you must change "GroupId" to "Group" in this line;

```
[ForeignKey("GroupId")]
```